# Cannot Install Dolphin Emulator From PPA

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, 21.04

I'm trying to run Dolphin Emulator on Kubuntu 21.04 using the [recommended PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Edolphin-emu/+archive/ubuntu/ppa). However, when I try to install it using `sudo apt install dolphin-emu-master`, I get an error about it not having a release file for 21.04/Hirsute. On the PPA, there is only a release file up to 18.04/Cosmic which is still being updated. I decide to edit the apt sources file to make it say `cosmic` rather than `hirsute`, however I just get an error about broken packages. I either need a way to ignore the broken packages that occurred due to me having to change the release name in the sources file, or a proper PPA that works with 21.04 that I can use. I know there is one in the default repositories, but that version is outdated and I need something from the beta or development channel for the additional features.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be maintained. It's not a very good idea to add PPAs to your system that are not maintained. Anyone can make a PPA and PPAs are not maintained or audited by Canonical.  Adding outdated PPAs can cause problems with your package management which can affect other applications that use the same dependencies. See: https://askubuntu.com/q/35629

Comment: @Nmath Well then how do I run Dolphin Emulator? There's no other way, but the repository has been updated 14 hours ago, so it's still maintained.

Comment: The build status from 14 hours ago is “failed”, which isn’t a great sign. Perhaps [the build instructions](https://dolphin-emu.org/docs/guides/building-dolphin-linux/) will allow you to run the emulator 

Comment: I don't see where you found that this PPA is recommended. The project development seems to be based on GitHub and they say nothing about the PPA and have build instructions for Linux.  Maybe the info you are using is outdated.  See: https://github.com/dolphin-emu/dolphin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following commands to remove unnecessary PPA and install from [official repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/dolphin-emu):

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:dolphin-emu/ppa

sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get install dolphin-emu
```

Also please note that AUR [says](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/dolphin-emu/) that this package is outdated 2021-09-11.

If you really need newer version - use the following options:

- install 5.0-15158 from [Snap](https://snapcraft.io/dolphin-emulator)

  ```
  sudo snap install dolphin-emulator --edge
  ```
- install 5.0-15158 from [FlatPak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.DolphinEmu.dolphin-emu)

  ```
  sudo apt install flatpak
  flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
  flatpak install flathub org.DolphinEmu.dolphin-emu
  ```
- compile from sources - follow [official wiki](https://github.com/dolphin-emu/dolphin/wiki/Building-for-Linux).

Comment: Adding universe doesn't work, you still get the error "E: Package 'dolphin-emu' has no installation candidate"